# How to queue up videos or media using mpv?

Tags: youtube-dl, mpv

In particular I'd like a command for mpv that will automatically play youtube links I add in order. For example, at a party I might want to queue up songs as we think of them, and have them automatically play.

Answer (score 0):

`man mpv`

```
 mpv [options] [file|URL|PLAYLIST|-]
```

...

```
  --playlist=<filename>
        Play  files according to a playlist file (Supports some common formats. 
        If no format is detected, it will be treated as list
        of files, separated by newline characters. Note that XML playlist 
        formats are not supported.)

        You can play playlists directly and without this option, 
        however, this option disables any security mechanisms that might be
        in place. You may also need this option to load plaintext files as playlist.
```